# How do I multiply two matrices in pyhton without numpy?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, transpose, matrix-multiplication

Implement  a  function  mat_mult_by_transpose(mat)  which  gets  a  valid  matrix
called  mat  and    returns  a  new  matrix  which  is  the  matrix  multiplication  of    and (), i.e. () ⋅ ().
Return a new matrix, without modifying mat2.
You may assume that the input matrix is not empty.

Example 1:

```
    mat = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] 
    mult_mat = mat_mult_by_transpose(mat) 
    print(mat) # [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]] 
    print(mult_mat) # [[5, 11, 17], [11, 25, 39], [17, 39, 61]]
```

Example 2:

```
    mat2 = [[0, 1, 2], [10, 11, 12], [20, 21, 22]] 
    mult_mat2 = mat_mult_by_transpose(mat2) 
    print(mult_mat2) # [[5, 35, 65], [35, 365, 695], [65, 695, 1325]]
```

This is my attempt:

```
def mat_transpose(mat):
    transposedMat= []
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(mat[i])):
        newMat= []
        for j in range(len(mat)):
                newMat.append(mat[j][i])
        transposedMat.append(newMat)
    return transposedMat

def mat_mult_by_transpose(mat):
    matT = mat_transpose(mat)
    mat2 = []
    for i in range(len(matT)):
        temp_list=[]
        for j in range(len(matT)):
            sum = 0
            for k in range(len(matT[0])):
                sum += mat[i][k] * matT[k][j]
            temp_list.append(sum)
        mat2.append(temp_list)
    return mat2
```

The error I ran into is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file0.py", line 156, in <module>
    mult_mat = mat_mult_by_transpose(mat)
  File "file0.py", line 97, in mat_mult_by_transpose
    sum += mat[i][k] * matT[k][j]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don’t understand where my mistake is…

Comment: Have you tried to [debug](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) it?

Comment: It seems that you misplace `i`, `j` and `k` in the reported line.

Comment: Maybe - but i tried rearranging them and also in all the examples I’ve seen this is the order they’re written. I’m looking for an explanation as to why they’re wrong or if it is something else that causes this (maybe earlier in the loops definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `mat_transpose()` works fine. Look at it in terms of dimensions.

Let `mat` has dimension `MxN` 
Hence `M = len(mat)` and `N = len(mat[0])`

Now `matT` will have dimension `NxM` 
Hence `N = len(matT)` and `M = len(matT[0])`

You need to traverse row of first matrix `mat`, i.e `i` ranges [0..M] 
then column of second matrix `matT`, i.e `j` ranges [0..M] 
and `k` should be ranging the common dimension which is [0..N]

Here is the code:

```py
def mat_mult_by_transpose(mat):
    matT = mat_transpose(mat)
    mat2 = []
    for i in range(len(mat)): # M,
        temp_list=[]
        for j in range(len(matT[0])): # M
            sum = 0
            for k in range(len(mat[0])): # N, you can use len(matT) also
                sum += mat[i][k] * matT[k][j]
            temp_list.append(sum)
        mat2.append(temp_list)
    return mat2
```